# Поменять по кол-ву нулей строки

Tags: c++

```
int main()
{
    const int N = 3;
    int m[N][N];

for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    for (int j = 0; j < N; j++)
        cin >> m[i][j];

int imax = 0;
for(int i = 0, max = 0, count = 0; i < N; i++)
{
    for(int j = 0; j < N; j++)
    {
        if(m[i][j] == 0)
            max++;
        if(count < max)
        {
            count = max;
            imax = i;
        }
    }
    max = 0;
}

int imin = 0;
for(int i = 0, min = 0, count = 0; i < N; i++)
{
    for(int j = 0; j < N; j++)
    {
        if(m[i][j] == 0)
            min++;
        if(count > min)
        {
            count = min;
            imin = i;
        }
    }
    min = 0;
}

if (imax != imin)
for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
      int temp = m[imax][i];
      m[imax][i] = m[imin][i];
      m[imin][i] = temp;
  }

cout<<imax<<"  "<<imin<<'\n';

for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
  for (int j = 0; j < N; j++)
      cout << m[i][j] << " ";
  cout << endl;
}

system("pause");
return 0;
}
```

Помогите, пожалуйста, нужно считать кол-во нулей в строках и поменять две строки местами, строку с максимальным количеством нулей и строку с минимальным. Вот все что с себя выжал, но код в редких ситуациях работает корректно. Если допустим в строке вообще нет нулей, а в какой-либо другой есть, то их менять не нужно, т.е. по идее максимум и минимум равны единице, но этого у меня не вышло сделать.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Давайте по порядку разбираться.

Вот этот кусок, должен по идее подсчитать индекс строки, где больше всего нулей, правильно?

```
int imax = 0;
for(int i = 0, max = 0, count = 0; i < N; i++)
{
    for(int j = 0; j < N; j++)
    {
        if(m[i][j] == 0)
            max++;
        if(count < max)
        {
            count = max;
            imax = i;
        }
    }
    max = 0;
}
```

Лучше разбить его на 2 части: одну, которая подсчитывает к-во нулей построчно и складывает в массив, и другую, которая находит в получившемся массиве индекс максимума (то есть номера строки, где наибольшее к-во нулей). Так и проще, и возможностей для ошибок меньше. Мы же не усложнять себе должны задачу, а упрощать, правда?

(Кстати, заметьте, что программисты всеми силами стараются *упрощать* задачи, которые стоят перед ними, пока они не станут очевидными.)

Этот же массив можно повторно использовать позже, для вычисления индекса минимума.

Попробуете?

Comment: Ну сейчас попробую

Comment: int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
  {
            count = 0;
            for (int j = 0; j < N; j++) 
   {
                if (m[i][j] == 0)
                    count++;
            }
        s[i] = count + 1;
        }

Вот так формируем массив, но вот какие теперь строки в зависимости от его значений менять и что делать с одинаковым кол-вом - тут я теряюсь

Comment: @RubyNub: о, отлично. теперь у вас есть массив `s`, в котором хранится количество нулей. найдите в нём индексы наибольшего и наименьшего элемента -- это будут ваши `imax` и `imin`.

Comment: @VladD, http://pastebin.com/beKHGCPK эта опять меняет с той в которой вообще нет, уже не знаю как с этим бороться

Comment: @RubyNub: ваша ссылка не открывается. насчёт того, что меняет с неправильной строкой -- смотрите, когда вы ищете `imin`, вы должны рассматривать только те строки, где есть нули, то есть где `s[i] > 0`. наверняка в этом проблема.

Comment: @VladD, спасибо, это я там реализовал, да другую малую ошибочку не заметил. Все вопрос решен

Comment: @RubyNub: отлично, разобрались! :)